# Javascript debugging in Firefox 3?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How can one find Javascript errors in Firefox 3? IE shows it by default, but how do you do it in Firefox? I do have Firebug, but no idea where to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the error console.

Tools > Error Console or Ctrl+Shift+J.

(This is a standard feature in Firefox, you don't need Firebug to use it.)

Comment: ...and a very overlooked feature at that.

Comment: @Raynos: Yes. I think that it has always been there. I found it mentioned for Firefox 2 at least.

Answer (score 1):

just open firebug, if there is an error it shows you the error in the console

maybe you have to enable the console first